# Illegal memory write causing recv() to return zero

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am somehow getting disconnected from a socket, or at least the value returned from `recv()` is zero. From what seems to trigger the problem I think it is an out-of-bounds memory write. However, I am outputting the value of my socket and that hasn't been corrupted.

Is there a way I can detect the "disconnection" without calling recv() (because I am already calling that to read the bytes, I am looking for something I can query throughout the code to detect exactly when the "disconnection" occurs)?

Is it possible for `recv()` to return zero due to an illegal memory write and yet the socket descriptor value remain unchanged?

Comment: Why do you think an out of bounds write is causing the problem?  What does tcpdump / wireshark show going across the network when this happens?

Comment: @dbush it only seems to happen when the application processes a large number of events. For fewer events there is no disconnection. So I process "batches" and when several large batches are received, thats when the problem seems to occur.

Comment: do you expect us to guess as to what your code is doing?   Strongly suggest post code that 1) cleanly compiles 2) exhibits the problem

Answer (score 2):

A return value of 0 from `recv` means EOF, i.e. the peer has closed its end of the connection (or at least shut it down for writing via `shutdown`). I don't see any reason to believe it should have something to do with memory clobbering on your side; with `recv` generally being a very thin syscall wrapper it would be very unlikely that anything you could do in userspace affects its behavior, even if your program has invoked undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No, you find out what happened on that socket **strictly** by reading/writing from/to it. There is no other (reliable) way to find out.

> Is it possible for recv() to return zero due to an illegal memory
>   write and yet the socket descriptor value remain unchanged?

If something went wrong, `recv` returns `-1` and sets `errno` accordingly (in that case, to `EFAULT`) rather than `0`.

You can analyze your side with a tool like AddressSanitizer or valgrind and Wireshark for the networking.

Comment: Would love to use address sanitizer. See my other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357631/undefined-symbol-what-next